# sending email with verification link while user subscribed to a site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am a beginner in .NET programming, so help me guys.
My question: When user is subscribing to the site, the values will be added in Sql DB, presently in the table data stored it will get "YES" status message while subscribing.
But, here starts the question- when they subscribe for the site, E-mail have to go to the subscriber's email address with verification link.
When user click this verification link, directly have to go to the website address.
Then simultaneously in SQL DB, the status message has to change to status "YES", which was
 already stored as "NO".
Please suggest me some site/link, which has full code of this problem or anything which helps me to find the solution.

Comment: what exactly do you want? can you be a bit more specific and try to be a bit more literate when you ask question?

Comment: hi,while user subscribe to site, email verification link  have to go t his Email ID and while clicking on his link it have to directly site login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, it might be worth you looking at the asp.net membership system, a walk-through can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx

As for the membership email scenario it's covered as part of a larger series of articles regarding the membership system on the '4 Guys From Rolla' site - https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153319/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is a common task in every server-side project using user registration.

1. When user registers in your site, create for him an unique confirmation key in DB. This can be an url-safe md5 like algorithm. You can use his unique username or email address to generate the confirmation key.
2. Email the confirmation link including name and confirmation key in parameters.
3. In confirmation page, check against DB if the confirmation key is correct for the username.
4. Update user in DB to confirmed.

Comment: There are optimal ways to do it, but this is one of the easiest

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the verification link in a way that some malicious person can't predict it and decides to call your website to subscribe or unsubscribe illegitimately your users.

For example, somewhere in your body you can have:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/unsubscribe.aspx?id=userId&token={some-guid-value-stored-in-your-db} > Click here to unsubscribe </a>
```

You could send the email like this:

```
private void SendEmail()
{
  string to = "jane@contoso.com";
  string from = "ben@contoso.com";
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
  message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
  message.Body = @"<a href="http://yoursite.com/unsubscribe.aspx?id=userId&token={some-guid-value-stored-in-your-db} > Click here to unsubscribe </a>";
  message.IsBodyHtml=true; //VERY IMPORTANT
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
 // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
 // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
 client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

  try {
    client.Send(message);
  }  
  catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}", 
   ex.ToString() );           
  }
}
```

On the `unsubscribe.aspx` you would read both, userid and guid value like so:

```
Page_Load
{
    string userid = Request.QueryString["id"];
    string guid = Request.QueryString["token"];

    //Query your database, find user matching this id and token chaning YES for NO to
    //unsbscribe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this videoo about [Implement the Registration Verification Pattern](http://www.asp.net/security/videos/implement-the-registration-verification-pattern), so you can use the similar approach to accomplish your task